# prove that for each $a\in S$ and$ r>0$ the set $A=\{x: d(x,a)=r \}$ is non-empty .

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(S,d)$ be a connected metric space which is not bounded . prove that for each $a\in S$ and $r>0$ the set $A=\{x: d(x,a)=r \}$ is non-empty .

My approach : Fix any $a\in S$ and $r>0$ .
Consider the function $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ given by $f(x)=d(x,a)-r $ .
$f(a)=-r<0 $ and there is $x'$ such that $f(x')=d(x',a)-r  > $ as $S$ is not bounded . So by IVT $c\in S$ such that $f(c)=0$ . This proves $c\in A$ .So A is not empty . As this is true for arbitrary  $a \in S $ and $r>0$  this is true for all $a\in S$ and $r>0$ .

Is my solution correct ?

Comment: Seems good to me.  Assuming you have proven the IVT on connected sets.

Comment: Note that this implies that $X$ has at least as many points as $\mathbb{R}$, as sets like that for a fixed centre partition up the space $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but here is one that I find more intuitive.

Let $U = \{x:d(x,a)<r\}$ and $V=\{x:d(x,a)>r\}$. These sets are nonempty because $S$ is unbounded. They are also open sets, since if $p\in U$ then the open ball with center $p$ and radius $d(p,a)$ is contained in $U$, and likewise for $V$. As $U\cap V=\varnothing$, this implies that $A\ne\varnothing$. Otherwise, $U$ and $V$ would constitute a separation of $S$, which contradicts the assumption that $S$ is connected.